# How to run a before each block only for Capybara specs in RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I have both Capybara JS specs and Rack Test specs. I want to have a `before :each` block only for the Capybara specs. All Capybara specs are JS.

I tried using `before :each, js: :true`, but the specs are not marked as JS. I am setting the default driver to webkit, so I don't have to mark each spec as JS.

So, how to run a `before :each` on Capybara specs and exclude Rack Test specs?

Comment: How are the capybara specs identified ?

Comment: Currently using :js. However, I could put them in a separate directory (like features). Or use a separate tag, like :jasmine.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this in your spec_helper should work:

```
Capybara.configure do |config|
  config.before(:suite) do
    # do before whole test suite
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    # do before each test
  end
end
```

Also, definitely is a good idea to separate out your features, so your spec folder looks like this:

```
/spec
  /controllers
  /features
  /models
```